# Dynamic BigQuery Schema using Auto Detection:Error Schema has no fields

Tags: google-bigquery, command-line-interface, schema, jobs

I am trying to mess with the auto detection feature in Bigquery and currently I am encountering issues on updating the schema on my table.

What currently I have done.

1. I created manually a dataset and table name in Bigquery.
2. Execute my first bq load command (Works perfectly fine):

```
bq --location=${LOCATION} load --autodetect --source_format=${FORMAT} ${DATASET}.${TABLE} ${PATH_TO_SOURCE}.
```

3. I try to append a new JSON object introduced with new field to update the current schema.
4. Execute 2nd bq load command:

```
bq --location=${LOCATION} load --autodetect --schema_update_option=ALLOW_FIELD_ADDITION --source_format=${FORMAT} ${DATASET}.${TABLE} ${PATH_TO_SOURCE}
```

5. Throws an error:

   > Error in query string.
   >   Error processing job. Schema has no fields.

I thought when `--autodetect` flag is enabled bq load command will not request for schema on your load job. Has anyone already encountered this issue?

First object:

```
  {
    "chatSessionId": "123",
    "chatRequestId": "1234",
    "senderType": "CUSTOMER",
    "senderFriendlyName": "Player"
  }
```

Second Object:

```
{
    "chatSessionId": "456",
    "chatRequestId": "5678",
    "senderType": "CUSTOMER",
    "senderFriendlyName": "Player",
    "languageCode": "EN"
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide a piece of the the first data you loaded and the data you're using to update? The error that you posted is the complete error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your steps but I couldn't reproduce the same error as you can see in the images below:

Loading first JSON
[image: Loading first JSON]

First table's data
[image: First table loaded]

Loading second JSON
[image: Loading second JSON]

Second's table data
[image: Second table loaded]

The only thing I changed in your data was the format: you provided a `JSON` and I turned it into a `NEWLINE DELIMITED JSON` (type of JSON that `BigQuery` expects).
You can find more information about it [here](http://jsonlines.org/).
Please let me know if it clarifies something for you.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks I'll probably gonna look on this one. Since basically wha I am trying to do. Cheers ! :)

Comment: I just ran into this. There's something wrong with the source: It's null, badly formatted, etc. 

This is why rmesteves was unable to recreate the error.